# Why is my code only outputting "O"?

Tags: java

```
public class checkerBoard
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int m = 6; //m is rows
        int n = 2; //n is columns

        char o = 'O';
        char x = 'X';

        for (int r = 1; r <= m; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++)
            {
                if (c+r % 2 == 0)               
                    System.out.print(x);

                else
                    System.out.print(o);

                if (c == n)
                    System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should be printing

XO
OX
XO
OX

But instead it prints

OO
OO
OO
OO

It's probably a really obvious solution but I'm new to this (obviously) and can't figure out what I did wrong.

This is Java, by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing `c+r % 2` to `(c+r) % 2`.

`%` takes precedence over `+`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Awesome! I'll try to make it a point to remember precedence. Forgot that spacing doesn't affect precedence, oops.

Always the simple stuff that messes it up. :(

Comment: Keep it up. We all keep the reference materials in bookmark when learning a new language.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `if (c+r % 2 == 0)` to `if((c+r) % 2 == 0)`

Comment: 2 mins late, no explanation and basically just restating the highest voted answer.

Comment: Well, I was the first one writing the answer but it's slow writing from my phone you know? No need to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your c+r inside parenthesis because % operator has precedence over + operator which is causing modulus to be executed before sum and causing error.

```
public class checkerBoard
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int m = 6; //m is rows
        int n = 2; //n is columns

        char o = 'O';
        char x = 'X';

        for (int r = 1; r <= m; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++)
            {
                if ((c+r) % 2 == 0)               
                    System.out.print(x);

                else
                    System.out.print(o);

                if (c == n)
                    System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very interesting that people here are so fast in solving problem that many solutions are already posted when they click "Post your answer"  :)

Comment: Indeed :). You have to be a fast typist to answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `%` takes precedence over `+`. So, you're code,finally,  must look like this :

```
public class checkerBoard { 
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        int m = 6; //m is rows
        int n = 2; //n is columns

        char o = 'O';
        char x = 'X';

        for (int r = 1; r <= m; r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
                if ((c+r) % 2 == 0){ //% takes precedence over +                
                    System.out.print(x);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(o);
                }
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```